# Controls used in windows 8 weather app

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

In the default weather app that comes with Windows 8 there is a forecast section that has 2 buttons and by clicking on those buttons the app will slide and show new content in that section. This is illustrated in the picture below:

[image]

[image]

This is really cool and i have been searching a lot how this can be performed or the type of controls used. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Bing Weather is an HTML app, but this is nothing special - a regular button that when clicked runs an animation of a RenderTransform on a panel that has its Clip property set.

Comment: I'd have thought that they're using CSS' "-ms-scroll-snap-points-x" property. Not sure how it would work in XAML, though.